# Questions about a simple LED circuit using the ULN2003A

Tags: led, transistors, transistor-array

I'm a newbie, and am trying to drive several independent LEDs using a transistor array in a 5-volt CMOS circuit. Here's what I've come up with, showing only the first LED:

[image: Schematic]

In the schematic, `LED_ENABLE` is the output of some logic IC in the circuit. I'm assuming that the LED has a voltage drop of 1.8 V and requires 20 mA of current.

Does this seem sane, or have I missed something? Specific questions:

1. I've tied `LED_ENABLE` directly to the base pin, because my understanding is that the ULN2003A's internal resistor is designed to let me do so. Is that safe to do without thinking further? It seems like the value of the resistor should need to depend on \$I_{CE}\$ and the transistor's gain, so I'm not sure how this can be one size fits all.
2. I chose the resistor voltage by calculating \$\frac{5 V - (0.9 V + 1.8 V)}{20 mA}=115 Ω\$ and rounding up, since the [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uln2003a.pdf) for the ULN2003A says that the collector-emitter voltage at saturation is 0.9 V for \$I_C=100 mA\$ (the lowest listed current). Is this the right calculation?
3. If I understand correctly, I don't need the `COM` pin. Is it sane to leave it floating?
4. And how about leaving the other base and collector pins floating? Maybe they should be tied to ground?
5. Anything else obvious I've missed?

Comment: Everything you say you said and did sounds fine. Either a component is dead OR you atre noy conncting as you think you are.

Comment: I'd just like to say, thank you for a well formulated, coherent, and to-the-point question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Correct: it is ok to tie directly to tbe base pin, given the internal resistor. The reason one size fits all, is the combined gain of the darlington pair is so high, and that the output pins' current ratings mean any current at the output within specs will be sustained by the internal resistor at the base.
2. Yes your calculation looks good.
3. Look at the circuit diagram below which shows how the darlington pairs are implemented. You can leave COM floating.
4. You can leave the other pins floating. They should have no bearing on your circuit, since as per the diagram below, they are independent (as long as you do not pull COM low).
5. Perhaps you have not wired it up correctly, or the chip is dead. For the sake of troubleshooting, try connecting COM directly to ground, which would be equivalent to all transistor pairs saturated on. The LED should light. Perhaps the LED's polarity is reversed. Sanity check by connecting pin 1C directly to ground.

[image]

Comment: "Try connecting COM directly to ground". COM pin should not be connected to GROUND! It's supposed to be connected to the 'Load Supply Voltage'.

Comment: Thanks for the quick point by point answer! To be clear: I'm designing, not trouble-shooting; I haven't built this yet. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some problem I missed in my design.

Comment: @m.Alin That would have no effect. No current would flow anywhere, given the diode polarity

Comment: @Jacobsa, in that case, your circuit looks perfect.

Comment: @Jodes The diode is there to protect the transistor in case you are switching an inductive load, such as a motor. It's called a flyback diode. In case of driving a LED you could leave the COM pin unconnected, but you should not connected it to GROUND!

Comment: Ah ok - I didn't consider that it might be used for that. Clever! I should have read the datasheet. It could still be used for taking all outputs low though. It would still work as an aid for troubleshooting if none of the outputs were going low.

Comment: @m.Alin I do not know why Jodes apologised. What he said in 5. was completely correct. It would simulate all drivers on if you grounded it, as he says, and would like all equipped EDs, subject to the total LED currents not being > com pin current spec. With one only LED it should work OK.

Comment: @Russell You're right, I read his answer in a hurry. I didn't see that he is connecting COM to GROUND _just for debugging purposes_. That should be fine :-)

Comment: @m.Alin: It's perfectly okay to connect the Com pin to ground if that is the effect that you desire.  For example, back in the bad old Disco days (80s), we used to make DJ lighting controllers for incandescent lamp matrix arrays that were mounted in either the ceiling or floor.  We would drive both the X & Y axis triac optos with 2803 drivers (8x8 or 16x16 matrix), then pull the Com pin for either the X or Y 2003 driver chip Low to select either the X or Y direction.  Saved many diodes!